# Using sinon fakeTimer with supertest lead to an error

Tags: node.js, automated-tests, mocha.js, sinon, supertest

When I use sinon fakeTimer with supertest, it leads to an error `Error: socket hang up`. Why and how to fix it, pls help ?

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: The function for your "it" block can take a parameter normally called "done". You then invoke it, `done()`, when you want to end the test. This might help you.

Answer (score 1):

It a very old question and I hope you found the answer, but maybe my answer helps to others.

Fake only the necessary "functions" with sinon. `useFakeTimers` fake `setInterval` and `setImmediate` js functiony by default so it cause the hang up.

Setup the `toFake` parameters of the `useFakeTimers` options

```
const sandbox = createSandbox();
sandbox.useFakeTimers({
    now: currentDate.getTime(),
    toFake: ['Date']
  });
// ... tests
sandbox.restore();
```

https://sinonjs.org/releases/v6.2.0/fake-timers/